# Display method in the linked list does not display the entire lists item

Tags: python, data-structures, methods, singly-linked-list

I'm a beginner in python and I wanted to create a single linked list and then add a node at the end of the list. but I have a problem...
When I want to display the items of the list it displays me the value of the last node that I've inserted.
What should I do to fix this issue??

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.info = value
        self.link = None


class SingleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None

    def create_list(self):
        n = int(input('enter number of nodes '))
        if n == 0:
            return
        for i in range(n):
            b = int(input('enter the element to be inserted '))

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        temp = Node(data)      #insertion in the empty linked list
        if self.start is None:
            self.start = temp
            return

        p = self.start
        while p is not None:
            p = p.link
        p.link = temp

    def display_list(self):
        if self.start is None:
            print('linked list is empty')

        else:
            print('list is: ')
            p = self.start
            while p is not None:
                print(p.info, "", end='')
                p = p.link
            print()


test = SingleLinkedList()
test.create_list()
data = 70
test.insert_at_end(data)
test.display_list()
```

Comment: Your "create_list" function doesn't store the entered elements anywhere.

Comment: I assume you're missing a line `self.insert_at_end(b)` inside the `for i in range(n)` loop of `create_list`.

Comment: There's also a bug in `insert_at_end`: the while-test should be `while p.link is not None`.

Comment: @Mahzad yes, but you are not using "b" for anything, and also, in the next iteration of the for loop, it'll be changed, so you lost that data.

Comment: Also, the `if n == 0:` part is not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got my mistakes, and fix them @Stef,  ekhumoro , Sasszem

Comment: @ekhumoro  by while p is not None, I mean the loop will break in the last node, why p is not correct and I have to use p.link?

Comment: @Mahzad Because the last `p.link` will *always* be `None`, so you need to check it *before* re-assigning `p` (otherwise, the next line will raise an attribute-error, since `p` will be `None`).